# Leibniz Integral Rule, integrating and differentiating wrt the same variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I read in a book:

> $$\int_{x=0}^{x=L} \frac{\partial p (x,t)}{\partial x} \mathrm dx =  \frac{\mathrm  d}{\mathrm  dx} \left( \int_{x=0}^{x=L} p (x,t) \mathrm dx  \right) $$
>
> This is a consequence of applying Leibniz's rule for differentiation  under the integral sign with constant upper and lower limits.

Is it correct? Isn't the quantity inside the parenthesis at the RHS independent of $x$, so that the RHS would be equal to $0$? Is there a typo?

Comment: My guess is that there is a typo and that the derivatives (both on the left and on the right hand side) should be with respect to t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake inside this formula, since this integral would be just p(x=L,t) - p(X=0,t).

The real formula is given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule  and works for the special case when the born of your integral are constants.

Comment: The next line in the book is indeed equating the RHS to $p(x=L,t) - p(x=0,t)$. I don't know why he wrote the line I put in the answer.

Comment: What are “the horn of your integral”?

Comment: But "born of the integral" I meant "the interval of integration" that has to be constant.
My mistake ! Wrong french translation ;)

Answer (score 2):

No it is wrong. Note that 
$$
\int_0^L p(x,t)\mathrm dx
$$
for any fixed $t=c$ is just a number. So, holding $t$ fixed and differentiating in $x$ is differentiating a constant (wrt x) and thus is $0$.

The author certainly meant $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$.